# Podkastkaptilo por vindoza telefono kun esperantaj podkastoj?

Tags: technology, resources

Mia podkastkaptilo ne montras la mojosajn esperantajn podkastojn, kies ekziston mi ja scias. Mi supozas, ke vi certe diros ke vindoza poŝtelefono aĉas, sed, ĉu iu scias pri podkastkaptilo, kiu fakte kaptas esperantajn podkastojn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La podkastoj kern.punkto kaj movada-vid.punkto devus esti aboneblaj per la "Aboni"-butono, kiuj troviĝas supre dekstre en la retejoj. Se vi iras per retumilo al http://kern.punkto.info kaj klakas la "Aboni"-butonon, ĝi devus aŭtomate trovi instalitajn podkaptilojn kaj aboni la podkaston. Bedaŭrinde la aliaj Esperantlingvaj podkastoj ne havas tian butonon. Tiujn vi povas aboni nur per mana aldono de la fluadreso aŭ, se vi estas bonŝanca, via podkaptilo konas ĝin.

Tio estas ĝenerala problemo de la podkastado, ke ne ekzistas komforta ĝenerale uzata vojo por konigi la fluadreson al la podkaptilo. Tiu "Aboni"-butono, kiu devenas de la germanlingva podkasta komunumo, provas solvi tion. Bedaŭrinde ĝi ne estas vaste konata ekstere de Germanlingvio.